# Rails 4 how to know if update has been executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in Rails 4:

```
mmkBase = Mmk::Base.find_or_initialize_by(id: id)  
mmkBase.update(name: name, city: city, country: country, address: address, region_ids: regionIds, latitude: latitude,
                       longitude: longitude)
```

The code is working ok, but now I would need to gather some statistics, like:

- Number of bases.
- Number of new bases.
- Number of loaded (updated) bases.

Number of bases is not a problem. Number of new bases, I think I could check if the object `mmkBase` returned by `find_or_initialize` comes with more attributes than just the id, for example with a name. 
However, I don´t know how can I check if the update operation is run.

Is there any way to know this? Is there a better way to achieve this? Maybe, I should use a more traditional way to do it, with a select first?

Comment: In response to "I don´t know how can I check if the update operation is run" - the [update](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update) method returns `false` if validations fail and the object is not saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to distinguish between an already existing record and a newly created record. On a new record which was only initialized by `find_or_initialize_by`, `new_record?` returns `true`. So for example you could write:

```
mmkBase = Mmk::Base.find_or_initialize_by(id: id)
new_base = mmkBase.new_record?
if mmkBase.update(name: name, city: city, country: country, address: address, region_ids: regionIds, latitude: latitude,
                   longitude: longitude)
  # update was successful
  if new_base
    new_bases += 1
  else
    updated_bases += 1
  end
else
  # error handling
end
```

Note that it is probably not a good idea to use `find_or_initialize_by` *with the ID of the record*. See  [Rich Peck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33647776/390808).

Comment: Is there any similar method to distinguish when update method is making an insert or an update?

Comment: @Rober: No, `update` only sets the attributes and saves the model: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update You have to get this information before. Maybe there is a more elegant way to do what you want to do, but you have to give more information to answer that (do you want the numbers for global updates in your app or just there in the method, is the code located in a loop? In a controller?), maybe in another question?

Answer (score 4):

> However, I don´t know how can I check if the update operation is run

You can simply use...

```
if mmkbase.update mkbase_params
 ...
else
 ...
```

This will invoke the [`update`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update) method, generating a response determined by whether it was successful or not (`true` = `success`; `false` = `validation failure`)

---

> Number of new bases

As mentioned, the [`new_record?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/new_record%3F) method is what you need here...

```
if mmkbase.new_record? #-> mmkbase hasn't been saved to db yet
```

---

I'd do this:

```
mmkBase.find_or_create_by(mmkbase_params) do |base|
   #do something if new base
end

private

def mmkbase_params
    params.require(:mmkbase).permit(:name, :city, :country, :address, :region_ids, :latitude, :longitude)
end
```

If you're having to pull this type of data by its primary key (`find_or_initialize_by id:`), you're in trouble... *how do you know if the primary key will remain constant?*

Of course, this is not always the case. Changing `user` details would require you to reference the user `id` - *however* that data is rigid. IE a user registered (with `name` and `email`), and you're now looking for *that* user (it *can't* be created on the fly).

I don't know your schema; anything which can be created like this should be referenced by its core data (`name`, `city`, etc)...

```
mmkbase.find_by(name: ....)
```

In relational databases, you need to be dealing with the *data*, not the primary keys. In other types of db, you can deal with indexes, but with this type of setup, it's much better to work with the pure data.

Comment: You are right, `find_or_initialize_by(id: id)` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -3):

You could probably check the `updated_at` timestamp on the object to see if it has been updated recently but the Rails 4 update method doesn't tell you whether an object was updated or not.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class

Comment: This is wrong. You are linking to an ancient doc. Since Rails 3, the `update` method is in `ActiveRecord::Persistence` module and it returns false if validations fail and object wasn't saved: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update